# Delete many-to-many in MySQL database with FastAPI SQLAlchemy [ Internal Server Error:'int' object has no attribute 'query'"]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to make test CRUD app for study, but I have problem with delete opperaction, because I have many-to-many relationship,I think.

Models:
class Book(Base):
**tablename** = 'books'

```
id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
title = Column(String(50))
isbn = Column(String(50))
pageCount = Column(INTEGER(11))
publishedDate = Column(DateTime)
thumbnailUrl = Column(String(100))
shortDescription = Column(String(500))
longDescription = Column(String(1000))
status = Column(String(50))

categorys = relationship('Category',cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True, secondary='bookcategories')
```

class Author(Base):
**tablename** = 'authors'

```
author_id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
author_name = Column(String(50))

books = relationship('Book',cascade="all, delete",passive_deletes=True, secondary='bookauthors')
```

class Category(Base):
**tablename** = 'categories'

```
category_id = Column(INTEGER(11), primary_key=True)
category_name = Column(String(50))
```

t_bookauthors = Table(
'bookauthors', metadata,
Column('book_id', ForeignKey('books.id', ondelete="CASCADE")),
Column('author_id', ForeignKey('authors.author_id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
)

t_bookcategories = Table(
'bookcategories', metadata,
Column('book_id', ForeignKey('books.id', ondelete="CASCADE")),
Column('category_id', ForeignKey('categories.category_id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
)

Service:

def remove(db: Session, id:int):
try:
book = db.query(Book).filter(Book.id==id).first()
if book:
db.delete(book)
db.commit()
return book
except Exception as e:
raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e)) #Error: "detail": " Details Error: Internal Server Error'int' object has no attribute 'query'"

How I can solve this?

I already read SQLAlchemy documentation by this topic and try solve this, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: You `remove` functiontakes one `Session` argument and one `int`. Looking at the error message, I suspect you swapped them.